# g suite with azure ad

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, google-workspace

We have domain **blabla.com** with gmail users:

```
user1@blabla.com
user2@blabla.com
user3@blabla.com
```

How I can make users connect through the Azure Control Panel to their 
gmail account without entering password and so on... using G Suite (Single 
Sign-On).
I tried to set up it by **Tutorial: Azure Active Directory integration 
with G Suite**
After my last attempt users got error:

```
AADSTS50020: User account 'XXX' from identity provider 'xxx.com' doesn't 
exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application 
'google.com/a/blabla.com' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as 
an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a 
different Azure Active Directory user account.
```

P.S. Domain blabla.com is already Verified on Azure Portal

Please write down exact steps to do this task without getting rid of existing gmail accounts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The gmail users accounts should be individually added to the G-Suite application as "guest users" in the **Azure Portal**.

First look for and add the users in "Home > domain > User - all users > New Guest user" and then "invite" each user in "Home > Enterprise applications - All applications > G Suite - Users and groups > Add Assignment > Users and groups"

A very clear explanation can be found in [Azure AD B2B collaboration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/what-is-b2b)

Non-admin users can invite "guest users" to use G-Suite in the Microsoft [Access Panel](http://myapps.microsoft.com)

Comment: thanks for answer
now I got this error message:




Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS65005: Misconfigured application. This could be due to one of the following: The client has not listed any permissions for 'AAD Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Or, The admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, Check the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the configured client application identifier. Please contact your admin to fix the configuration or consent on behalf of the tenant. Client app ID: xxxxxxx.

Comment: I would suspect a problem with the "SAML Signing Certificate" and recreate/replace to Gmail

Comment: What do you mean? I downloaded certificate from Azure AD and put it into G-Suite

Comment: Yes that’s what I mean, do all again

Comment: Yo can't never trust the error messages, often with old or misleading advice. It feels like Azure side can't negotiate (handshake access) with the G Suite. Can you login to the G Suite side and check if there is any log of the login attempt?
So my impression is the login credentials are corrupted or had expired.
Probably worth reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-sign-in-problem-federated-sso-gallery?/?WT.mc_id=DMC_AAD_Manage_Apps_Troubleshooting_Nav#no-resource-in-requiredresourceaccess-list

Comment: By the way, Azure should send an invitation to the G Suite account an it should be accepted

Comment: so, the issue was resolved by modifying Identifier (Entity ID) to --> google.com/a/DOMAIN_NAME

P.S. If I set up and use Provisioning will my existing gmail users be present without any changes?